# how to handle com.ibm.ejs.cm.portability.DuplicateKeyException

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I am getting ibm.ejs.cm.portability.DuplicateKeyException while saving a data Object. It is actually coming when i am trying to insert the same row in the Table and the condition is that i cant avoid it. So i need a handler but while putting this exception in try catch block i m getting compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to "merge" your Hibernate Object. This means that the Entity will only be inserted if it is not existing. Otherwise, the Entity will be updated.

I don`t understand why your try catch block is causing a compilation error. Do you have some code example?